# How separate date and time that was previous recorded with delimiter (;) in txt file?

Tags: delphi

I'm with difficulties for divide, a date and a hour, that already was recorded in a .txt file with a delimitador (**;**) between these two elements (date and hour). I want compare, date present on .txt file with actual date, hour present on .txt file with actual hour.

Then until now have this:

```
var

DATE_NOW, HOUR_NOW, DATE_BLOCK, HOUR_BLOCK, BLOCKED: string;
f: Textfile;
Hours: TDateTime;

procedure Block24H();
begin
if FileExists('DateHourFile.exe') then
begin
deletefile('DateHourFile.exe');
end;

AssignFile(f, 'DateHourFile.exe');
  try
  ReWrite(f); 
  DATE_NOW := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', Date);
  HOUR_NOW := FormatDateTime('t', Hours);
    WriteLn(f, DATE_NOW + ';' + HOUR_NOW); // Here is recorded on same line with a separator (;)
  finally
    CloseFile(f);
  end;
end;

procedure ReadingFile();
begin

if FileExists('DateHourFile.exe') then
begin
if FileExists('DateHourFile.exe') then
begin
   AssignFile(f, 'DateHourFile.exe');
   Reset(f);

   While not eof(f) do begin

     Readln(f,DATE_BLOCK,HOUR_BLOCK); 

     DATE_NOW := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', Date);
     HOUR_NOW := FormatDateTime('t', Hours);

     if (DATE_BLOCK = DATE_NOW) and (HOUR_BLOCK = HOUR_NOW) then
     begin
     BLOCKED := '1'; // blocked!
     end;

     Closefile(f);
     exit;
     end;
     end;

end; 

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the entire line and then manually divide it up into the two substrings before you can then compare the values. `Readln()` cannot divide the lines on the `;` delimiter for you, like you are trying to do with it (it can divide up lines on whitespace, though). Use `Pos()` and `Copy()` to extract the two substrings, eg:

```
procedure ReadingFile();
var
  line: string;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  if FileExists('DateHourFile.exe') then
  begin
    AssignFile(f, 'DateHourFile.exe');
    Reset(f);

    While not eof(f) do
    begin
      Readln(f, line); 

      Idx := Pos(';', line);
      DATE_BLOCK := Copy(line, 1, Idx-1);
      HOUR_BLOCK := Copy(line, Idx+1, MaxInt);

      DATE_NOW := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', Date);
      HOUR_NOW := FormatDateTime('t', Hours);

      if (DATE_BLOCK = DATE_NOW) and (HOUR_BLOCK = HOUR_NOW) then
      begin
        BLOCKED := '1'; // blocked!
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    CloseFile(f);
  end;
end;
```